# Mesmo colocando a <table> dentro de uma <div> não consigo definir margem

Tags: javascript, html

Coloquei uma table dentro de um arquivo `.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link href="StyleMain.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <div id="tableDiv">
        <table border="0" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="40%" class="infoView" id="torrentNameInf">Filmão</td>
                    <td width="15%" align="center" class="infoView">Filme Bem loko</td>
                    <td width="10%" align="center" class="infoView">1059</td>
                    <td width="10%" align="center" class="infoView">2159</td>
                    <td width="5%" align="center" class="infoView"><img id="downButton" src="images/downButton.png"/></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</html>
```

E dentro do `StyleMain.css` eu coloquei

```css
#tableDiv {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

E quando eu chamo a `.html`

```
$.post('linha.html', function (html) {
    for(var i=0; i<25; i++) {
        $('#baseTorrent').append(html);
    }
});
```

Ela não cria o espaço entre as `divs`

[image: Imagem do resultado]

Comment: Porque estás a fazer append de vários html? incluindo o <!doctype>, StyleMain.css, e várias tabelas (vais ficar com id's repetidos, #tableDiv) na mesma página, isso não é suposto acontecer. tenta só fazer append às linhas que precisas

Comment: @Miguel Eu preciso de todas, na verdade eu queria chamar esse div por uma função PHP, mas como não é possível eu apenas joguei em uma .html e chamei por JS.

Comment: Sim mas o ficheiro que deves chamar, é suposto conter elementos a adicionar à tua página (ex: linhas/tabelas) não um documento inteiro, nunca deves ficar com ids repetidos também, começa por aí

Comment: @Miguel E como eu faria para chamar apenas a `tableDiv` ??

Comment: Suponho que o ficheiro onde tens o teu  `#basetorrent` seja já um documento html, sendo assim não precisas de voltar a charmar tudo... Tira tudo do ficheiro de onde chamas a tabela e deixa só, `<div class="tableDiv">...
    </div>` ... E nem reparei antes, mas essa tabela nem estava sequer dentro da tag `<body>`

Comment: Facilitaria se houvesse algum código rodando para testarmos e te ajudar.
Já experimentou fazer este exemplo no [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) ou [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) ?

Comment: @Miguel Eu retirei tudo de dentro da .html, deixei apenas a <div>, porem continua sem as margens.

Comment: @fernandosavio Eu chamo os os arquivos pelo nome, porem eu não achei como fazer isso pelos sites que me passou.

Comment: @fernandosavio O único problema que estou enfrentando é o fato do CSS não colocar as margens na `tableDiv`.

Comment: Então faz o que o @Miguel falou, deixe apenas o HTML que tu quer adicionar e não um documento inteiro.
Vou criar um resposta com um exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criei um CodePen para demonstra que só é necessário o bloco de código ser inserido na página, sem necessidade de adicionar inúmeras `<html>` tags.

http://codepen.io/fernandosavio/pen/EZNEdX

Pra melhor visualização adicionei também o snippet:

```js
// apenas simulando o que deveria ser recebido por ajax
var template = [
  '<div class="table-container">',
    '<table border="0" width="100%">',
        '<tr>',
            '<td width="40%" class="infoView torrentNameInf">Filmão</td>',
            '<td width="15%" align="center" class="infoView">Filme Bem loko</td>',
            '<td width="10%" align="center" class="infoView">1059</td>',
            '<td width="10%" align="center" class="infoView">2159</td>',
            '<td width="5%" align="center" class="infoView">⬇️</td>',
        '</tr>',
    '</table>',
  '</div>'
].join('');

var container = $('#container');

$('#click-me').on('click', function(){
  container.append(template);
});
```

```css
/* só para ficar mais fácil de ver */
#container { padding: 15px; }
#click-me { margin: 10px; }


.table-container {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.table-container table {
  background: #CCC;
}

.table-container tr {
  height: 35px;
}

.table-container td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button id="click-me">Click Me</button>
  <div class="table-container">
    <table>
      <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="40%" class="infoView torrentNameInf">Filmão</td>
            <td width="15%" align="center" class="infoView">Filme Bem loko</td>
            <td width="10%" align="center" class="infoView">1059</td>
            <td width="10%" align="center" class="infoView">2159</td>
            <td width="5%" align="center" class="infoView">⬇️</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Isso significa que teu arquivo `linha.html` deveria ser apenas

```
<div class="tableDiv">
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="40%" class="infoView" id="torrentNameInf">Filmão</td>
                <td width="15%" align="center" class="infoView">Filme Bem loko</td>
                <td width="10%" align="center" class="infoView">1059</td>
                <td width="10%" align="center" class="infoView">2159</td>
                <td width="5%" align="center" class="infoView"><img id="downButton" src="images/downButton.png"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

E o teu CSS deveria estar na página onde o JS é executado.

Também te aconselho a usar apenas uma `<table>` e importar apenas os `<tr>`

Comment: Tente um padding-top na classe tableDiv